xelatex compile teaser header image title text does not display
Title doesn't display properly when compiling teaser header image with XeLaTeX on Overleaf
Switching to pdfLaTex is fine, but I need to use xeLaTex
This is the format of the IEEE TVCG journal：
\documentclass[journal]{vgtc}                     % final (journal style)

% \documentclass[journal,hideappendix]{vgtc}        % final (journal style) without appendices
% \documentclass[review,journal]{vgtc}              % review (journal style)
% \documentclass[review,journal,hideappendix]{vgtc} % review (journal style)
%\documentclass[widereview]{vgtc}                  % wide-spaced review
%\documentclass[preprint,journal]{vgtc}            % preprint (journal style)


\usepackage[slantfont,boldfont]{xeCJK}


\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xspace,xpunctuate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ie}{{i.e.,}\xspace}
\newcommand{\eg}{{e.g.,}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ea}{{et~al\xperiod}\xspace}
\newcommand{\aka}{{a.k.a.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\etc}{{etc\xperiod}\xspace}

%% If you are submitting a paper to a conference for review with a double
%% blind reviewing process, please use one of the ``review'' options and replace the value ``0'' below with your
%% OnlineID. Otherwise, you may safely leave it at ``0''.
\onlineid{0}



%% declare the category of your paper, only shown in review mode
\vgtccategory{Research}


\vgtcpapertype{Application}

%% Paper title.
\title{AttentionViz: A Global View of Transformer Attention}


%% Author ORCID IDs should be specified using \authororcid like below inside
%% of the \author command. ORCID IDs can be registered at https://orcid.org/.
%% Include only the 16-digit dashed ID.
\author{%
  Catherine Yeh, 
  Yida Chen,
  Aoyu Wu,
  Cynthia Chen,
  Fernanda Vi\'egas, and 
  Martin Wattenberg
}

\authorfooter{
  %% insert punctuation at end of each item
  \item Authors are with Harvard University. Vi\'egas  and Wattenberg are also with Google, but this work was done at Harvard. Emails: \{catherineyeh, yidachen, aoyuwu, fernanda, wattenberg\}@g.harvard.edu, cynthiachen@college.harvard.edu
}

%% Abstract section.
\abstract{Transformer models are revolutionizing machine learning, but their inner workings remain mysterious. In this work, we present a new visualization technique designed to help researchers understand the \textit{self-attention} mechanism in transformers that allows these models to learn rich, contextual relationships between elements of a sequence.
The main idea behind our method is to visualize a joint embedding of the \textit{query} and \textit{key} vectors used by transformer models to compute attention. Unlike previous attention visualization techniques, our approach enables the analysis of global patterns across multiple input sequences. We create an interactive visualization tool, AttentionViz (demo: \url{http://attentionviz.com}), based on these joint query-key embeddings, and use it to study attention mechanisms in both language and vision transformers. We demonstrate the utility of our approach in improving model understanding and offering new insights about query-key interactions through several application scenarios and expert feedback. 
}

%% Keywords that describe your work. Will show as 'Index Terms' in journal
%% please capitalize first letter and insert punctuation after last keyword
\keywords{Transformer, Attention, NLP, Computer Vision, Visual Analytics}

%% A teaser figure can be included as follows
\teaser{
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/overview_new.png}
  \caption{AttentionViz, our interactive visualization tool, allows users to explore transformer self-attention at scale by creating a joint embedding space for \textcolor{ForestGreen}{\textit{queries}} and \textcolor{magenta}{\textit{keys}}. \textbf{(a)} In language transformers, these visualizations reveal striking visual traces that can be linked to attention patterns. Each point in the scatterplot represents the query or key version of a word, as denoted by point color. Users can explore individual attention heads (left) or zoom out for a ``global'' view of attention (right). \textbf{(b)} Our visualizations also divulge interesting insights in vision transformers, such as attention heads that group image patches by hue and brightness. Border color denotes query embeddings of a patch (\textcolor{ForestGreen}{green}) or key embeddings (\textcolor{magenta}{pink}). \textbf{(c)} Sample input sentences (from~\cite{jiang2020neural}) and \textbf{(d)} images (synthetic dataset) are provided for reference.}
  \label{fig:teaser}
}
% % Uncomment below to disable the manuscript note
% \renewcommand{\manuscriptnotetxt}{}

%% Copyright space is enabled by default as required by guidelines.
%% It is disabled by the 'review' option or via the following command:
%\nocopyrightspace


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LOAD PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Tell graphicx where to find files for figures when calling \includegraphics.
%% Note that due to the \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{} call it is no longer necessary
%% to provide the the path and extension of a graphics file:
%% \includegraphics{diamondrule} is completely sufficient.
\graphicspath{{figs/}{figures/}{pictures/}{images/}{./}} % where to search for the images

%% Only used in the template examples. You can remove these lines.
\usepackage{tabu}                      % only used for the table example
\usepackage{booktabs}                  % only used for the table example
\usepackage{lipsum}                    % used to generate placeholder text
\usepackage{mwe}                       % used to generate placeholder figures

\usepackage{float}


%% We encourage the use of mathptmx for consistent usage of times font
%% throughout the proceedings. However, if you encounter conflicts
%% with other math-related packages, you may want to disable it.
\usepackage{mathptmx}                  % use matching math font

\begin{document}

\firstsection{Introduction}

\maketitle

\input{sections/sec1-intro}
\input{sections/sec2-background}
\input{sections/sec3-related}
\input{sections/sec4-goals}
\input{sections/sec5-visdesign}
\input{sections/sec6-system}
\input{sections/sec7-evaluation}
\input{sections/sec8-conclusion}


%% if specified like this the section will be ommitted in review mode
\acknowledgments{%
We would like to thank all the participants in our user interviews for their time and invaluable insights. We also thank the anonymous reviewers for helping us improve this paper with their thorough and constructive comments. Finally, we are grateful for the thoughtful feedback and support provided by the members of the Harvard Insight + Interaction Lab throughout this project. %
}


\bibliographystyle{abbrv-doi-hyperref}
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv-doi-hyperref-narrow}
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv-doi}
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv-doi-narrow}

\bibliography{main}


%% ^^^^^   FOR IEEE VIS, EVERYTHING HERE MAY BE INCLUDED IN THE    ^^^^^ %%
%% 2-PAGE ALLOTMENT FOR REFERENCES, FIGURE CREDITS, AND ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS %%

\appendix 


\end{document}


The logs and output files are as follows:
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
‪/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty‬
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.
‪/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty‬
Package xeCJK Warning: Fandol is being set as the default font for CJK text. Please make sure it has been properly installed.
‪./main.tex‬
Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolSong-Regular" does not contain requested Script "CJK".
‪./main.tex‬
Font shape `TU/ptm/m/n' undefined
‪./main.tex‬
Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolHei-Regular" does not contain requested Script "CJK".
‪./main.tex‬
Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolFang-Regular" does not contain requested Script "CJK".
‪./main.tex‬
Font shape `TU/ptm/m/it' undefined
‪./main.tex‬
Font shape `TU/ptm/b/n' undefined
‪./main.tex‬
Font shape `TU/lmss/bx/sc' undefined
‪./main.tex‬
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
‪./main.tex‬
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
‪./output.bbl‬
Underfull \hbox (badness 2057) in paragraph at lines 485--485
enter image description here
I tried to change to pdfLaTex compilation, can show the title of the header Fig1, but can not use Chinese!
I've asked chatgpt, and it gave advices as follows:

Used the xeCJK package and set the SimSun font as the main CJK font.
Uses the setmainfont command to set Times New Roman as the main font.
The caption package is included to enhance control over captions.
Checks that the image path is correct and the image exists.

I've confirmed all but the first one，I use the default Chinese fonts

x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/717907/36296
